# split a String into letters in dart-flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

i want to split a word into characters. "Amir Abbas" it contains one space. i use:

```
List<String> singleWord = string.trim().split("");
```

but final result is:

```
A, m, i, r, " ", "", A, b, b, a, s
```

what is "" character? how to exclude it?
*I use it in flutter and ios emulator.*

Answer (score 3):

The following code does not give your result. It is not splitting an empty character for me. Try typing your string again, eventually you might have a hidden illegal character?

```
void main() {
  List<String> singleWord = "Amir Abbas".trim().split("");
  singleWord.forEach((element){
    print(element);
  });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the list with the **where** method and exclude the empty spaces

```
void main() {
  List<String> a = ["a", "b", ""];
  List<String> b = a.where((e) => e != "").toList();
  print(a); // ["a", "b", ""]
  print(b); // ["a", "b"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working perfectly for me in dart pad and in my application.Run the application again and can u submit the output again

Answer (score 0):

[image]Try this approach by replacing trim() and just using split(). You can alter the below code according to your need

```
var names = "Amir and Abbas";
  List<String> namesSplit = names.split(" ");
  
  for(var i=0;i<namesSplit.length;i++){
    for(var j=0; j<namesSplit[i].length;j++){
      print(namesSplit[i][j]);  
    }
    
  }
```

Output:
A
m
i
r
a
n
d
A
b
b
a
s

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the runes and get all the letters from A-z.

```
List<String> singleWord = runes.where((rune) => rune > 64 && rune < 123).map((rune) => String.fromCharCode(rune)).toList()

print(singleWord); // prints [A, m, i, r, A, b, b, a, s]
```